# Manifolds with Compressible Boundary

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, definition, low-dimensional-topology, surgery-theory

I recently stumbled over the following terminology, but since I am not really familiar with geometric topology I having a hard time to understand it correctly. So, lets start with the following definitions:

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a (sufficiently nice) $3$-manifold.

1. A properly embedded surface $\mathcal{S}$ is called "compressible", if there is a "compression disk" D, which is a disk embedded in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $D\cap\mathcal{S}=\partial D$, such that the intersection is transverse and such that $\partial D$ does not bound a disk inside $\mathcal{S}$.
2. There is also the notion of $\partial$-compressible surfaces, which  is a properly embedded surface $\mathcal{S}$ such that there is a $\partial$-compression disk", which is a disk embedded in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $D\cap\mathcal{S}=:\alpha$ and $D\cap\partial\mathcal{M}=:\beta$ are arcs in $\partial D$ with the property $\partial D=\alpha\cup\beta$ and $\alpha\cap\beta=\partial\alpha=\partial\beta$ and such that $\alpha$ does not bound a disk in $\mathcal{S}$ together with another arc in $\partial\mathcal{S}$.

(Are this definitions correc?) I have two question to this terminology:

1. Is there any relation between these two different concepts?
2. What does an author mean when he say "a manifold has a compressible boundary"? So, which one of the two concepts mentioned above does one mean and with respect to which surface? (I originally thought they just take $\partial\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{S}$ in this case, but this surface is certainly not *properly* embedded...

Does maybe someone has some good reference clarifying these definitions?

Comment: Looking at a simple example, let $M=\mathbb{R}^3$. If $S$ is just the 2-sphere then the usual embedding is not compressible. If $S$ is a torus with a standard embedding it is compressible. Is this the intended meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i. Both definitions you gave are correct with few minor remarks:

(a) "Sufficiently nice" should be removed. Instead you should say that you are working either with topological manifolds and **locally flat** submanifolds, or that you are working with PL manifolds and PL submanifolds, or you are working with smooth manifolds and smooth submanifolds.

(b) Sometimes the definition of incompressibility is applied differently to 2-spheres in 3-manifolds.

(ii) If you want some intuition of how the two notions (incompressible and $\partial$-incompressible) are related, the best way that I know is to use the notion of the **double of a manifold along its boundary**. Let $M$ be a manifold with boundary. Form the product $P=M\times \{0, 1\}$ and consider an equivalence relation on $P$: $(x, 0)\sim (x,1)$ for all $x\in \partial M$. The quotient space $P/\sim$ is called the **double** of $M$ and (sometimes) denoted $DM$. This is a manifold with empty boundary. Now, if you have a properly embedded surface $S\subset M$, then you can apply the doubling construction to $S$ (inside $M$) as well and obtain a natural embedding
$$
DS\to DM. 
$$
It is a pleasant exercise to check that if $S$ is $\partial$-compressible in $M$, then $DS$ is compressible in $DM$. A harder result (I do not have a reference) is that the converse is true as well.

(iii) Lastly, regarding **incompressible boundary**: yes, indeed, $\partial M$ is not properly embedded in $M$. However, you can repeat **the same definition** of an incompressible surface for $\partial M$ and thus, obtain the definition of a manifold with incompressible boundary.